# How to describe formal functions around the node of an algebraic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, singularity-theory, formal-completions

Let $C$ be a smooth proper curve over an algebraically closed field $k$ with $p,q \in C$ two distinct points. Let $X = C / p \sim q$ be the nodal curve obtained by gluing $p$ and $q$. Denote the node by $n \in X$ and the normalization map by $\pi : C \to X$.

We can relate the functions on $X$ with those on $C$ by the exact sequence:
$$
  0 \to \mathcal{O}_X \to \pi_*\mathcal{O}_C \overset{\rho}{\to} k \to 0
$$
where $\rho(f) = f(p)-f(q)$. In other words, the functions on $X$ are functions on $C$ which assume the same value on $p$ and $q$.

Let $A = \mathcal{O}_{X,n}$ and $B = (\pi_*\mathcal{O}_C)_n = \mathcal{O}_{C,p\cup q}$. It is a standard fact that $\hat A \simeq k[[x,y]]/(xy)$.

> Could we choose $x$ and $y$ as local analytic functions coming from $C$ (possibly defined near $p$ and $q$)?

Moreover, by classification of torsion free sheaves we must have $B\otimes_A \hat A \simeq \langle f_1,f_2 | yf_1=xf_2 = 0 \rangle$. So we ask again:

> Could we choose $f_1$ and $f_2$ to be local analytic functions defined on $C$?

By a local analytic function near $p \in C$, I mean an element of $\hat{\mathcal{O}}_{C,p}$. Therefore, I'm looking for explicit isomorphisms where $x,y$ and $f_1,f_2$ are somewhat natural.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure I have understood your question correctly, but here goes.

$B\otimes_A\hat{A}=\widehat{\mathcal{O}_{C,p}}\times\widehat{\mathcal{O}_{C,q}}$ and the latter is just $k[[x]]\times k[[y]]$, where $x,y$ are the local analytic parameters at $p,q$. You have the natural map to $k$ from this ring, given by $(f(x),g(y))\mapsto f(0)-g(0)$. The kernel is $\hat{A}$. I hope this clarifies the situation.

Comment: Yes that is very helpful, I wasn't aware of the isomorphism $B\otimes_A \hat A \simeq \widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{C,p}\times \widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{C,q}$. Could you say a few words on how to derive this identification? That would then completely settle the issue for me. Many thanks!

Comment: For a semilocal ring (like your $B$), if you complete it with respect to the Jacboson radical, you get the the product of the completions of the localizations with respect to their maximal ideals, and can easily be seen by the inverse limit definition. When you take $B\otimes_A \hat{A}$, this precisely what you are dong, since $B$ is a finitely generated module over $A$.